# Create and read a Temporary file in a Django Command

Tags: python, django, temporary-files

I need to read a flow url as csv then this is what I do:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Admin command to import feed'

    def _download_flow(self, url):
        req = requests.get(url, stream=True)

        if req.status_code == 200:
            tmp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, suffix=".csv")
            for line in req.iter_lines():
                tmp.write(line)
            return tmp
        raise Exception('error:{}'.format(req.status_code))

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        catalog = self._download_flow(options['url'])
        with open(catalog.name, 'rU') as csvfile:

            reader = csv.DictReader(
                csvfile,
                delimiter=';',
                quotechar='"')

            for row in reader:
                raise Exception(row)

        catalog.close()
```

Basically, from an url, I create a temporary csv file. Then, now I want to parse this file to work with lines but I don't know why my exception is not raised. (My file has content, i've checked).
Do you have any clue to help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem came from the _download() method, the correct way to construct the file is:

```
    def _download_flow(self, url):
        req = requests.get(url, stream=True)

        if req.status_code == 200:
            tmp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, suffix=".csv")
            for chunk in req.iter_content():
                tmp.write(chunk)
            return tmp
        raise Exception('error:{}'.format(req.status_code))
```